# Python numpy array has weird truth conditions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I set up:

```py
board = np.array([[2., 0., 2.],[0., 2., 0.],[2., 0., 1.]])
```

Then `np.diagonal(board)` returns `array([2., 2., 1.])`, as you would expect. And `np.diagonal(board) == 1` returns `array([False, False,  True])`, again, as expected. But `np.diagonal(board).all() == 1`returns `True`, which should be false and `np.diagonal(board).all() == 2`returns `False`, which is correct.

What is going on here?

Comment: Why should the first one be `False`?? `np.diagonal(board).all()` equals `True` for your array. If you compare `True` with `1` you get `True`.  If you compare `True` with `2` you get `False`

Answer (score 0):

When you call `all()` on the diagonal array, it checks if all the elements are `True`. You provided a `float` array  not `bool`. Everything non-zero is treated as `True`, so `all()` returns `True`. Then in pure Python, True == 1 (not just non-zero as in your numpy call), so == 2 is `False`

Comment: huh ok, so I cannot use `np.diagonal()`  to check if all diagonal values meet a certain condition? Say I want `if np.diagonal(board) == 3:`?

Comment: Ah, I now understand your intention. You need to change how you are using `all()`: `np.all(np.diagonal(board) == 3)`. You have to do the element-wise comparison first.